# Craftercms: Accessing a xml file in Site's own Spring Application Context

Tags: java, groovy, content-management-system

I created a "org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean" bean using the site's own Spring application context, according to: http://docs.craftercms.org/en/latest/site-administrators/engine-site-configuration.html

This bean is declared as follows:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="projectName.dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/projectdb"/>

<bean id="projectName.sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="projectName.dataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="sqlmap-config.xml" />
</bean>
```

I need to specify a xml in the "configLocation" property value, this bean will load it and process it. 
The question is:
Where should I put the xml file in order to make it accesible for the beans?

I know one way is to have the xml file in an engine overlay; that works, but I wonder if it is possible to place it somewhere else (work-area as an example), in order to avoid creating an overlay?